# log4j tcp appender and logstash source host

Tags: java, tomcat, elasticsearch, log4j, logstash

I am shipping my logs from a tomcat instance to another machine using a log4j socketappender. On this remote server, I have logstash setup to do the transforms on the data, which then is forwarded to my elastic search cluster. For some reason I can't get the original host of the logs to show up in elastic search. I get the host of the logstash forwarders, but the host from the original log even does not persist through the pipeline.

My logstash config

```
input {
  log4j {
    mode => "server"
    port => "4560"
  }
  tcp {
    port => "4561"
    codec => "json"
    type => "access"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => [ "source_ip", "@source_host" ]
  }
  if [type] == "access" {
    mutate { remove_field => "something-private" }
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event['@timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].localtime('-05:00')"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event['@pretty_timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].strftime('%A, %B %e %Y at %l:%M:%S %p')"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host        => "elasticsearch.host"
    cluster     => "log-cluster"
    protocol    => "http"
  }
}
```

All the logs come through fine, but I wanna have their source host in them as well so I can tell what servers they are coming from.

An average logevent coming through would be like this...

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.01.28",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "AUsyNvDyCso0hZPOUVfM",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "Executing query: Removed",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-01-28T15:23:56.331-05:00",
    "host": "10.253.1.112:31441",
    "path": "org.blahblah",
    "priority": "INFO",
    "logger_name": "org.blahblah",
    "thread": "http-bio-8080-exec-13",
    "class": "?",
    "file": "?:?",
    "method": "?",
    "source_ip": "@source_host",
    "@pretty_timestamp": "Wednesday, January 28 2015 at  3:23:56 PM"
  },
  "sort": [
    1422476636331,
    1422476636331
  ]
}
```

Any idea how to tune this to include the correct source host?

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, default, SOCKET, FILE
log4j.appender.default=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.default.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.SOCKET=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.SOCKET.Port=4560
log4j.appender.SOCKET.RemoteHost=${logHost}
log4j.appender.SOCKET.ReconnectionDelay=1000

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log_home}neuron-logging.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p %t %c - %m%n
```

I add some catalina options -DlogHost= and -Dlog_home= blah blah

Comment: Can you post your log4j config too. Or whatever means you are transporting this logs to the logstash server

Comment: @VineethMohan I added my log4j config, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use GELF? logstash-gelf (https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf) for example provides a flexible configuration and you'll get the original hostname out of the box. In addition to that, you can provide data from MDC and supply static settings.

Example config:

```
log4j.appender.gelf=biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j.GelfLogAppender
log4j.appender.gelf.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.gelf.Host=udp:localhost
log4j.appender.gelf.Port=12201
log4j.appender.gelf.ExtractStackTrace=true
log4j.appender.gelf.FilterStackTrace=true

# This are static fields
log4j.appender.gelf.AdditionalFields=fieldName1=fieldValue1,fieldName2=fieldValue2

# This are fields using MDC
log4j.appender.gelf.MdcFields=mdcField1,mdcField2
log4j.appender.gelf.DynamicMdcFields=mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields
log4j.appender.gelf.IncludeFullMdc=true
```